# create link to open files (xlsx, pdf, docx) in browser in Office 365

Tags: office-365, rest, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

I have created a custom page

It makes an ajax call and then results are shown in the page

```
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Library Name')/items?$top=1000&$select=Title,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef/Title&$expand=FieldValuesAsText",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //some code
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
```

Using the results, I create an anchor tag to open files

```
"<a target='_blank' href='{0}' class=''><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> View Document</a>".format(row.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef);
```

Here the problem is, when I have a xlsx file, it gets downloaded instead of opening in browser using office webapps

Can we add a query string to the url so that it opens up the file instead of downloading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `?web=1` to the URL of the file and then it will open it in the browser.

Modify your code somewhat as:

```
"<a target='_blank' href='{0}' class=''><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> 
View Document</a>".format(row.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef + "?web=1");
```

In case of Office documents, you can also use the `LinkingUrl` property as below, wont work for PDF documents but for that you can use null handling as below :

use the endpoint as:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Library Name')/items/items?
$top=1000&$select=Title,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef,FieldValuesAsText/FileRef/Title,
File/LinkingUrl&$expand=FieldValuesAsText,File
```

After that in your code use it somewhat as:

```
var fileUrl = "";
if(row.LinkingUrl.length > 0){
    fileUrl = row.LinkingUrl;
}else{
    fileUrl = row.FieldValuesAsText.FileRef + "?web=1";
}

"<a target='_blank' href='{0}' class=''><i class='fa fa-eye'></i>
 View Document</a>".format(fileUrl);
```

Reference - [Making a link to a document in sharepoint open in browser](https://www.evokeit.com/blog/making-a-link-to-a-document-in-sharepoint-2013-open-in-browser)

[Link to “open in browser” with Office Web Apps](http://paulryan.com.au/2013/link-to-open-in-browser-with-owa/)